# How can I get A value of ELF file?

Tags: linux, elf

I'm Beginner of Linux System and I'm studying ELF File Format reading this Documents(http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf).
But When i see related Document about Relocation, There is Strange Things in Relocation Calculation.
i know according to relocation type, it applies different way to calculate.
But look at this.

When R-type is R_386_RELATIVE, this document says the way to calculate "B + A".
However What is "A" meaning exactly? and How can I get this "A" Value in ELF File?

Please give me ur merciful answer.......;

Comment: From the top of my mind, I think it is relative to the current IP, that is the address of the memory location where this value will be stored, but I don't have the docs to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From document you mentioned:

> **`R_386_RELATIVE`**
>
> The link editor creates this relocation type for dynamic linking. Its offset member gives a location within a shared object that contains a value representing a relative address. The dynamic linker computes the corresponding virtual address by **adding** **the virtual address at which the shared object was loaded to the relative address**. Relocation entries for this type must specify 0 for the symbol table index.
>
> **A**
>
> This means the **addend** used to compute the value of the relocatable field.
>
> **B**
>
> This means the **base address at which a shared object has been loaded into memory during execution**. Generally, a shared object file is built with a 0 base virtual address, but the execution address will be different.
>
> **Addend**
>
> As shown above, only **`Elf32_Rela`** entries contain an **explicit addend**. Entries of type **`Elf32_Rel** store an **implicit addend** in the location to be modified. Depending on the processor architecture, one form or the other might be necessary or more convenient. Consequently, an implementation for a particular machine may use one form exclusively or either form depending on context.
>
> **Base Address**
>
> To compute the base address, one determines the memory address associated with the lowest **`p_vaddr`** value for a **`PT_LOAD`** segment. One then obtains the base address by truncating the memory address to the nearest multiple of the maximum page size. Depending on the kind of file being loaded into memory, the memory address might or might not match the **`p_vaddr`** values.

So it boils down to next:

- **A** is **addend** and calculated from **`Elf32_Rel`** or **`Elf32_Rela`** structure
- **B** is **base address** and calculated from **`p_vaddr`**. Particular calculation depends on architecture.

You can observe relocation section of some binary/library file using `readelf -r`.